# jQuery how to replace url folder name with regex?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

> Sorry that I've misleading in the question before, let me amend the
>   question!!!

All, I need a jQuery/JavaScript function that can replace ALL URL folder name in a string. For example, from (zh-hant to zh-hans);

```
<a href="http://somedomain.com/zh-hant/folder1/folder2">http://somedomain.com/zh-hant/folder1/folder2</a>
```

Change to

```
<a href="http://somedomain.com/zh-hans/folder1/folder2">http://somedomain.com/zh-hans/folder1/folder2</a>
```

I've tried the below code but no use. none of those are changed.

```
var fromStr = '<a href="http://somedomain.com/zh-hant/folder1/folder2">http://somedomain.com/zh-hant/folder1/folder2</a>';    
var str = fromStr.replace(/\*zh-hant*/g, 'zh-hans');
```

Could anyone help?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why do you have `\*` in the regexp? There's no `*` in the folder name.

Answer (score 0):

First, the [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) only works on form elements (text inputs, etc.). Instead, you need to use the [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method to change the text within an element.

Secondly, both the `val()` and `text()` methods in jQuery get a value/text when you call it without an argument and sets a value/text when you pass it a string. It cannot update the value in-place. So once you've retrieved the value and done the replace on it, you must assign it back to the element using the `val()` method again.

```
var str = $(this).val().replace(/\*zh-hant*/g, 'zh-hans');
$(this).val(str);
```

This can be further shortened to:

```
$this.val( $(this).val().replace(/\*zh-hant*/g, 'zh-hans') );
```

Comment: `<a>` doesn't have a value. It should be `.attr('href')`

Comment: @Barmar I realized that halfway through and I'm updating.

Answer (score 0):

Use regex `/zh-hant/g` and core JS `href` and `innerText` properties like,

```js
$('a').each(function() {
  this.href = this.href.replace(/zh-hant/g, 'zh-hans');
  this.innerText = this.innerText.replace(/zh-hant/g, 'zh-hans');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://somedomain.com/zh-hant/folder1/folder2">http://somedomain.com/zh-hant/folder1/folder2</a>
```

Comment: Also `.attr('href')`

Comment: Yes @Barmar, I was updating my answer, and `href` & `innerText` are more faster than using the `text()` and `attr()`. Right?

Answer (score 0):

You pass the URL to `URL` constructor to get the `.pathname` of the URL, use `RegExp` `/^\/zh-hant/` to replace `"/zh-hant"` with `"/zh-hans"`

```js
var a = document.querySelector("a");
var url = new URL(a.href);
var res = url.origin + url.pathname.replace(/\/zh-hant/, "zh-hans");
a.href = a.textContent = res;
console.log(a.href);
```

```html
<a href="http://somedomain.com/zh-hant/folder1/folder2">http://somedomain.com/zh-hant/folder1/folder2</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<a>` elements don't have a value. You need to replace it in the text and the `href` attribute. You also have mistakes in the regexp; you don't really need a regexp since you're just matching exact text.

```
var newURL = $(this).attr('href').replace('zh-hant', 'zh-hans');
$(this).text(newURL).attr('href', newURL);
```

Comment: What occurs if `zh-hant` is also included in other part of the URL, for example as part of domain name?

Comment: This will replace the first match. Solving that would require a more complicated parse of the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't updated the `<a>` tag...

To update use `text()` or `html()` instead of `val()`. `.val()` is used for form elements.

```
$(this).text($(this).text().replace(/\*zh-hant*/g, 'zh-hans'));
```

to Update `href`

```
$(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href').replace(/\*zh-hant*/g, 'zh-hans'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var $a = $(this);
var str = $a.text().replace(/zh-hant/g, 'zh-hans');

$a.attr("href", str).text(str);
```